# What can be used instead of parse_qs function

Tags: python, deprecated, feedparser, python-2.4

I have the following code for parsing youtube feed and returning youtube movie id. How can I rewrite this to be python 2.4 compatible which I suppose doesn't support `parse_qs` function ?

```
YTSearchFeed = feedparser.parse("http://gdata.youtube.com" + path)
videos = []
for yt in YTSearchFeed.entries:
    url_data = urlparse.urlparse(yt['link']) 
    query = urlparse.parse_qs(url_data[4])
    id = query["v"][0]
    videos.append(id)
```

Comment: I think it has been moved: http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume your existing code runs in 2.6 or something newer, and you're trying to go back to 2.4?  `parse_qs` used to be in the `cgi` module before it was moved to `urlparse`.  Try `import cgi`, `cgi.parse_qs`.

Inspired by [TryPyPy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555569/trypypy) comment, I think you could make your source run in either environment by doing:

```
import urlparse # if we're pre-2.6, this will not include parse_qs
try:
    from urlparse import parse_qs
except ImportError: # old version, grab it from cgi
    from cgi import parse_qs
    urlparse.parse_qs = parse_qs
```

But I don't have 2.4 to try this out, so no promises.

Comment: So use: `try: from cgi import parse_qs; urlparse.parse_qs = parse_qs \n except ImportError: pass`

Comment: Thanks, but it's only your answer... or just a small note on how to make use of it. Feel free to incorporate it, the better answers the better :)

Comment: Why the `urlparse.parse_qs = parse_qs` line? I'm pretty sure this will fail, and `urlparse` won't be defined at this point.

Comment: @benhoyt Because he already calls `urlparse.parse_qs`, so if we just say 'use cgi', he'll have to substitute the call. If he monkeypatches the module (and you're right, that has to be after importing urlparse), any calls to parse_qs should work OK.

Answer (score -3):

I tried that, and still.. it wasn't working.

It's easier to simply copy the parse_qs/qsl functions over from the cgi module to the urlparse module.

Problem solved.